# Jira rest client in javascript giving error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, cors, jira-rest-api

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: "http://myJira.com/rest/api/2/issue/MA-6614/comment",
            username : "myusrName",
            password : "myPwd",
            success: function (data) {
                 console.log( "Sample of data:", JSON.stringify(data)); 

            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
              console.log( "errorMessage:", errormessage); 
            }
        });
});


</script>
</head>
<body> 
</body>
</html>
```

While running the above code I am getting **SyntaxError: missing ; before statement** error.
I read somewhere Access-Control-Allow-Origin should be used to solve problem. But I don't find a good documentation anywhere about how to use with Jira.

**"UPDATE"**
The above error I am getting if I have already loggedin in jira. If I logout in jira and then run the above code then getting error **"NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - http://myjira.com/rest/api/2/issue/MA-6614/comment?callback=jQuery1102010440085066514837_1388216960965&_=1388216960966"**

It seems the above code has two problem.
1. It is not able to authenticate in jira.
2. if we already authenticate in jira (that means browser has cookies)and make the request then syntax error is shown because of jsonp.

Comment: you have to post username and pwd to url right?

Comment: NO. I have to add username and password in http hearder. something like AUTHENTICATION : "usrname:password"
And jquery does it for u if u use username and password keys.

Comment: @MohdAdnan, so isn't possible to make it just with using javascript?

Comment: @PimentaDev. They revoked support. Not possible now. You have to use server side authentications. refer the below answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I got the answer.
Support in jira is revoked for authenticating from javascript. Iitally jsonP was the option but now it is not possible.
We have to do server side authentication of jira.
Example here

> https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Basic+Authentication

Comment: You can do this with javascript.

Comment: @beplaya: Can you tell me how to do this with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript.

```
function request(){
  var xhr = getXHR();

  xhr.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled, false);

  xhr.open("GET", baseURL+"/rest/api/2/issue/KEY-1", false);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa("admin:admin"))
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.send();
}
```

Ensure that it is synchronous and jira server conf has:

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"